# How do you show that the player loses his money? (Color Game)

Tags: r, probability

I have to solve this problem for school:

Three colored dice are being tossed and the player will bet money to one of the 6 colors. A player wins the same amount, twice the amount, or three times the amount of money he bet if the color he chose matches the colors from the 3 dice that has been rolled. Suppose that a player only bets one color for every round. Simulate this game and show that a player will eventually lose his money.

I have the code simulating the game. However, I don't know how to show that the player will eventually lose his money.

Here is the code in R:

```
dice = c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green", "orange", "violet")

win = 0
lose = 0
sims = 10000
multiplier = 0
ctr = 0
bet = 1

consecutive = 0

while (ctr != sims) {
    rolls <- sample(dice, 3)
    chosen_color <- sample(dice, 1)

    for (x in rolls) {
        if (chosen_color == x) {
            multiplier = multiplier + 1
        }
    } 
    winnings = bet * multiplier

    if (winnings == 0) {
        lose = lose + 1
        multiplier = 0
    }
    if (winnings > 0) {
        consecutive = consecutive + 1
        win = win + 1
        multiplier = 0
    }
    ctr = ctr + 1
}

print("Results:")
print(paste("Games won: ", win))
print(paste("Games lost: ", lose))
print(paste("Probability of winning: ", win/sims))
print(paste("Probability of losing: ", lose/sims))
```

I think there should be a money variable and it's output should be 0. But I don't know how to incorporate it into the program.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you're off to a good start. Some ideas. (1) This problem is called "gambler's ruin" and searching the web for that term will find some resources. (2) I think that the way to interpret the question is the following: "he will eventually lose his money" means that if you start with a fixed amount, and then keep adding or subtracting from what you have at each step, you will eventually reach zero. (3) Try organizing the code by having a function which takes as an input the current amount of money and simulates one turn, and returns the resulting amount (either adding or subtracting).

Comment: About (2), keep in mind that for some scenarios (e.g. starting with a lot of money and betting only a little on each turn), it could take many turns to reach zero. My guess is that the expected number of turns to reach zero is small if you bet a lot on every turn, e.g., bet all the money you have, so maybe try that first, and then make smaller bets and see what happens.